# Secret-sharing scheme that can be "audited" without auditing code?

Tags: secret-sharing

I am designing an app that allows (among other things...) users to divide a secret into 2 shards and was planning to use Shamir Secret Sharing (SSS) to do so.

However, I want to allow users of my app (who may not be coders...) to double-check--without having to audit my code--that my implementation of SSS is not flawed.

In other words, using another implementation of SSS available elsewhere (e.g. on the web or on GitHub), users of my app should ideally be able to obtain the same 2 shards as the ones provided by my app. I understand that, considering the random data used in SSS to compute the shards, this request may not even make sense at all since it may simply be impossible by design...

If that is indeed the case, which other reliable public solution/algorithm could my app use to: 
a) separate a secret into 2 shards,
b) allow anyone to recompute these 2 shards outside of my app.

Thanks a lot for your kind support!